# Determining memory consumption of ImageMagick convert

Tags: linux, memory, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to find out the maximum memory consumption (which is marked as private) of ImageMagicks convert.

Therefore I'm using `smem`, `psutil` and `free`.

With `free` and `psutil` (which reports RSS) I'm getting around 9.5GB memory consumption

**Problem:**
When running `smem` I get sometimes 9.5GB and sometimes 12.5GB on the same image.

Looking at the smem source I see that `/proc/$pid/smaps` is being used for calculation.

While getting the 12.5GB from `smem` I took a snapshot of the `smaps`-File:

[image: smaps].

The start address is different. The end-address is equal.
Both 'memory blocks' are reporting `private_dirty` > 6GB (therefore the smem-result of ~12GB).

Do I miss something, could this be a bug in `smaps`or why those `private_dirty` values can't be counted together?